# regex grouping and re-ordering

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, stringr

I am afraid I have a regex question. I would like to extract the first group of a string, which is 1 digit, leave out 2nd group, which is 2 digits, and then extract the ending 5 digits as 3rd group.

In my opinion it should look like: `str_extract(a, "(\\d{1})(\\d{2})(\\d{5})\\1\\3")`. But that doesn't work.

Sample data is here and also the wanted outcome, but with a different expression:

```
library(tidyverse)

d <- tibble(a = as.character(as.integer(runif(10, 1e8, 2e8))) )

d %>%
  mutate(want_but_wrong_regex = str_remove(a, "(?<=\\d)\\d{2}")) # 

# A tibble: 10 x 2
#a         want_but_wrong_regex
#<chr>     <chr>               
#  1 103016397 1016397             
#2 164356395 1356395             
#3 134615352 1615352             
#4 176581897 1581897             
#5 127035705 1035705             
#6 158055182 1055182             
#7 193991176 1991176             
#8 147845896 1845896             
#9 177083273 1083273             
#10 129086338 1086338
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `str_replace`, rather than `str_extract` (thank @AnilGoyal's dummy data), i.e.,

```
> str_replace(strings, "(\\d{1})(\\d{2})(\\d{5})", "\\1\\3")
[1] "133333" "245678" "023456"
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong way.  You're capturing groups but not extracting these.  Use string substitution functions like `gsub` with capturing groups in `pattern` argument and `groups reference` in `replacement argument` and you'll get results as desired

```
strings <- c('12233333', '23345678', '00123456')
gsub('(\\d{1})(\\d{2})(\\d{5})', '\\1\\3', strings)

[1] "133333" "245678" "023456"
```

Comment: Good `gsub` answer, upvoted! Or we can use `gsub("(?<=^\\d{1})\\d{2}", "", strings, perl = TRUE)`

Comment: Yeah true, this way we are replacing 2nd and 3rd digits by nothing and using lookarounds.  Actually there can be many ways to deal regex.  But here OP reached upto a certain point and had difficulty in perceiving that how the capture groups will work so I chose this one.  Thanks for upvote :) I voted yours already

Answer (score 2):

Since the position is fixed why you not extract the string using substring or similar functions instead of regex ? They are usually faster than regex extraction.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

d %>% mutate(res = str_c(str_sub(a, 1, 1), str_sub(a, 4, 9)))

#.          a     res
#1  103016397 1016397
#2  164356395 1356395
#3  134615352 1615352
#4  176581897 1581897
#5  127035705 1035705
#6  158055182 1055182
#7  193991176 1991176
#8  147845896 1845896
#9  177083273 1083273
#10 129086338 1086338
```

Or in base R -

```
transform(d, res = paste0(substr(a, 1, 1), substr(a, 4, 9)))
```